# I tried using MouseRegion class to change the cursor shape when hovered on a TextFormField but it is not working as expected

Tags: flutter, cursor

```
    class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EditProductScreenState createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}
class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              **MouseRegion(
                cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
                child: TextFormField(),)**
}
}
```

MouseRegion is not working as expected.
When I hover the cursor over the TextFormField, the cursor is not getting changed.

Can someone please explain how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `TextFormField` to IgnorePointer.

```
MouseRegion(
      cursor: SystemMouseCursors.wait,
      child: IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: true,
        child: TextFormField(),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: You can try to pass "cursor: SystemMouseCursors.wait" in TextFormField widget.
IgnorePointer ignore this widget and it rewrites a cursor type

Answer (score 0):

use `RichText`, full widget with  [selectable text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68535201/10157127)

```
 Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Phone us:',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 24,
            ),
            children: [
              TextSpan(
                text: '+123 1231 231',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),

                ///change your cusorStyle
                mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
                recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                  ..onTap = () async {
                    ///do the thing you want
                    final _url = "tel:+1 555 010 999";
                    await canLaunch(_url)
                        ? await launch(_url)
                        : throw 'Could not launch $_url';
                  },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```